# How can I install the latest version of Sun Java (JRE)?

Tags: software-installation, package-management, java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I install Oracle Java JRE 7?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56104/how-can-i-install-oracle-java-jre-7)

Is there a reliable method to install the current version of Sun Java?  Update 18 is in the repos, but it looks like Sun is up to update 21? I haven't yet found what I would consider to be reliable instructions that make much sense to the layman.

Comment: Any special needs that require you to install latest version on java? You can always install the java from Oracle instead of the one in official repo.

Comment: I'm also curious about whether/how you can install Sun/Oracle Java with apt-get. Traditionally I've always installed latest official JDK (not just JRE as I develop software against it) outside the packaging system.

Comment: If this is about **JRE**, as accepted answer suggests, the `programming` tag should be removed. (And [the other Java question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5567/how-to-install-the-sun-java-jdk) posted today *should* be tagged `programming`.)