# How can I install Sun/Oracle's proprietary Java JDK 6/7/8 or JRE?

Tags: java, software-installation, jdk, jre

I want to install **Oracle's JRE** and to update to the latest version with the Software Updater when they released. Is there a Ubuntu package that is provided by Canonical or Oracle?

Before release Java 7, I followed [this way](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5459/how-can-i-install-the-latest-version-of-sun-java-jre) to install **Java 6**.

But it doesn't work for **Java 7**. There is no package `sun-java7-xxx`. How can you install **Java 7**?

Comment: I wrote a blog post with a very detailed explanation on how to install Java 7 on Natty, both OpenJDK's and Sun's: [http://brunoreis.com/tech/installing-java-ubuntu-natty/](http://brunoreis.com/tech/installing-java-ubuntu-natty/) OpenJDK is installed from the PPA provided by Damien Lecan, and Sun's is installed manually. As far as know, until now that is the only guide that is correct both in the steps and the explanation. If you find any problems, post a comment there and I will try to fix it. Good luck.

Comment: I would also like to point out that using OpenJDK is more than a viable alternative: it is also the [reference implementation now](https://blogs.oracle.com/henrik/entry/moving_to_openjdk_as_the).

Comment: openJdk is not supported by banks applets or by other software. example: Aptana Studio

Comment: link to "this way" seems to reveal...no description of a way?

Comment: @ElzoValugi I think you might need Iced Tea to use bank applets. It's based on OpenJDK.

Comment: @GKFX no, for this specific bank IcedTea was not working and the bank was supporting only Oracle's Java. Meanwhile they quit using Java and I think it was a wise decision.

Comment: How come you never accepted an answer?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install Java?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48468/how-do-i-install-java)

Comment: Alternatively you can use https://sdkman.io/. I posted a full answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49507160/how-to-install-jdk-10-under-ubuntu/53083341#53083341

Comment: THIS PAGE IS WAY OUT OF DATE. Oracle Java 6/7/9 have reached end of life. Java 8 cannot be installed from the webupd8team PPA as the Oracle licence was changed in April 2019. You can now only use the method of downloading the *.tar.gz archive and following the installation method below.

Answer (score 905):

There is a [similar answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/56119/44179) on how to install JRE 7.

## Install Java JDK

### The manual way

- [Download](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) the 32-bit or 64-bit Linux "compressed binary file" - it has a ".tar.gz" file extension.
- Uncompress it

  `tar -xvf jdk-8-linux-i586.tar.gz`   (32-bit)

  `tar -xvf jdk-8-linux-x64.tar.gz`   (64-bit)

  The JDK 8 package is extracted into `./jdk1.8.0` directory. N.B.: Check carefully this folder name since Oracle seem to change this occasionally with each update.
- Now move the JDK 8 directory to `/usr/lib`

  ```
  sudo mkdir -p /usr/lib/jvm
  sudo mv ./jdk1.8.0 /usr/lib/jvm/
  ```
- Now run

  ```
  sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0/bin/java" 1
  sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javac" "javac" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0/bin/javac" 1
  sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javaws" "javaws" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0/bin/javaws" 1
  ```

  This will assign Oracle JDK a priority of 1, which means that installing other JDKs will [replace it as the default](https://askubuntu.com/q/344059/23678). Be sure to use a higher priority if you want Oracle JDK to remain the default.
- Correct the file ownership and the permissions of the executables:

  ```
  sudo chmod a+x /usr/bin/java
  sudo chmod a+x /usr/bin/javac
  sudo chmod a+x /usr/bin/javaws
  sudo chown -R root:root /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0
  ```

  N.B.: Remember - Java JDK has many more executables that you can similarly install as above. `java`, `javac`, `javaws` are probably the most frequently required. This [answer lists](https://askubuntu.com/a/68227/14356) the other executables available.
- Run

  ```
  sudo update-alternatives --config java
  ```

  You will see output similar to the one below - choose the number of jdk1.8.0 - for example `3` in this list (unless you have have never installed Java installed in your computer in which case a sentence saying "There is nothing to configure" will appear):

  ```
  $ sudo update-alternatives --config java
  There are 3 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

    Selection    Path                                            Priority   Status
  ------------------------------------------------------------
    0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1071      auto mode
    1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1071      manual mode
  * 2            /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0/bin/java                   1         manual mode
    3            /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0/bin/java                   1         manual mode

  Press enter to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: 3
  update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0/bin/java to provide /usr/bin/java (java) in manual mode
  ```

  Repeat the above for:

  ```
  sudo update-alternatives --config javac
  sudo update-alternatives --config javaws
  ```

**Note for NetBeans users!**

You need to [set the new JDK as default](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2809447/1505348) editing the configuration file.

---

If you want to enable the Mozilla Firefox plugin:

```
32 bit:
ln -s /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0/jre/lib/i386/libnpjp2.so ~/.mozilla/plugins/

64 bit:
ln -s /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0/jre/lib/amd64/libnpjp2.so ~/.mozilla/plugins/
```

N.B.: You can link the plugin (`libnpjp2.so`) to `/usr/lib/firefox/plugins/` for a system-wide installation (`/usr/lib/firefox-addons/plugins` from 15.04 onwards). For Ubuntu 13.10, the path to the plugin directory is `/usr/lib/firefox/browser/plugins/`.

Depending on your configuration, you might need to update the apparmor profile for Firefox (or other browsers) in `/etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/ubuntu-browsers.d/java`:

```
# Replace the two lines:
#  /usr/lib/jvm/java-*-sun-1.*/jre/bin/java{,_vm} cx -> browser_java,
#  /usr/lib/jvm/java-*-sun-1.*/jre/lib/*/libnp*.so cx -> browser_java,
# with those (or adapt to your new jdk folder name)
/usr/lib/jvm/jdk*/jre/bin/java{,_vm} cx -> browser_java,
/usr/lib/jvm/jdk*/jre/lib/*/libnp*.so cx -> browser_java,
```

Then restart apparmor:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apparmor restart
```

### The easy way (Obsolete)

> **Note:** WebUpd8 team's PPA has been discontinued with effective from April 16, 2019. Thus this PPA doesn't have any Java files. More information can be found on [PPA's page on Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/java). Hence this method no longer works and exists because of hostorical reasons.

The easiest way to install the JDK 7 is to do it with the Web Up8 Oracle Java OOS. However, it is believed that this PPA is sometimes out of date. Also note [the dangers of using a PPA](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35629/are-ppas-safe-to-add-to-my-system-and-what-are-some-red-flags-to-watch-out).

This installs JDK 7 (which includes Java JDK, JRE and the Java browser plugin):

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
# or if you want JDK 8:
# sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
# these commands install Oracle JDK7/8 and set them as default VMs automatically:
# sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-set-default
# sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-set-default
```

*[Source](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/01/install-oracle-java-jdk-7-in-ubuntu-via.html)*

N.B.: Before someone screams *this is against the Oracle redistribution license* - the PPA does not actually have Java in the personal repository. Instead, the PPA directly downloads from Oracle and installs it.

## The Script way

If you're on a fresh installation of Ubuntu with no previous Java installations, this script automates the process outlined above if you don't want to type all that into a console. Remember, you **still need to download Java from Oracle's website** -- Oracle's links are not `wget` friendly.

Before using this **make sure** that this script is in the same directory as the `.tar.gz` file extension that you downloaded and there are **no** files that start with jdk-7 in the same folder. If there are, please move them out of the folder temporarily. Remember to make the script executable (`chmod +x <script's file>`).

```
#!/bin/sh

tar -xvf jdk-7*
sudo mkdir /usr/lib/jvm
sudo mv ./jdk1.7* /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0/bin/java" 1
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javac" "javac" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0/bin/javac" 1
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javaws" "javaws" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0/bin/javaws" 1
sudo chmod a+x /usr/bin/java
sudo chmod a+x /usr/bin/javac
sudo chmod a+x /usr/bin/javaws
```

If you want to install the plugin for Firefox then add this to the end of the script:

```
mkdir ~/.mozilla/plugins
ln -s /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0/jre/lib/amd64/libnpjp2.so ~/.mozilla/plugins/
sudo /etc/init.d/apparmor restart
```

## Check if installation was successful

You can check if the installation succeeded with the following command:

```
java -version
```

You should see something like

```
java version "1.8.0"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0-b132)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.0-b70, mixed mode)
```

You can check if the JRE Mozilla plugin has been successful by using the [official oracle website](http://java.com/en/download/installed.jsp).

---

For Java 6: [How do I install Oracle JDK 6?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67909/how-to-install-oracle-java-jdk-6)

Comment: Is necessary to do all the same process to update it?

Comment: I am noticing that the 'update-java-alternatives' commmand from the java-common package doesn't work with Oracle JDK. Anyone know why?

Comment: This worked successfully for me installing the 32-bit JDK on Ubuntu 12.04LTS, except that I was getting `bash: /usr/bin/java: No such file or directory` when I tried to run `java -version`. [`apt-get install libc6-i386`](http://askubuntu.com/a/207750/818) fixed the problem.

Comment: How about the man ($JAVA_HOME/man) pages? you need to --slave them as in @BigWhale's answer. Also, are the jars located in lib ($JAVA_HOME/lib) needed? How do you properly install those as well?

Comment: Thank you for the tutorial. To make it work in Chromium (32bit), apart from Firefox, run this in terminal: `sudo ln -s /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0/jre/lib/i386/libnpjp2.so /usr/lib/chromium-browser/plugins/` To make it work in Chrome (32bit): `sudo mkdir /opt/google/chrome/plugins && cd /opt/google/chrome/plugins && sudo ln -s /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0/jre/lib/i386/libnpjp2.so /opt/google/chrome/plugins/` In some Ubuntu based distros, if you want to make Flash work in Firefox, just add that file to `/usr/lib/firefox-addons/plugins`

Comment: +1 for (a.o.) " Oracle's links are not wget friendly" - I had a hell of a time trying to get these files (headless server, had to install GUI + browser to get at them).

Comment: I suggest the use `/usr/local/*` in place of `/usr/*` for any manual installation like here. That way what you install manually wont clutter up with stuff managed by package manager and make manual installation more manageable

Comment: I strongly recommend the manual way out of this. It is the most reliable. The PPA doesn't work anymore since Oracle Java is licensed. And the script above assumes you are using the compiler and the runtime and that version on it is out of date.

Comment: How can I install manpage?

Comment: You can also use http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/java-package.

Comment: Isn't /usr/lib meant for package distributions? If you are using source, I assume it would be put in /usr/local instead. Probably /usr/local/java8 would be a good location.

Comment: How can I install both jdk7 and jdk8 in the manual way?

Comment: Use proper filename when using terminal for example use ' sudo mv ./jdk1.8.0_66 /usr/lib/jvm/ ' when using java jdk version 8 update 66

Comment: I get this error  update-alternatives: error: alternative path is not absolute as it should be: usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_102/bin/java
after running sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_102/bin/java" 1  what m i doing wrong thanks.

Comment: I tried the easy way and I got this error 
E: Package 'oracle-java8-installer' has no installation candidate

Answer (score 172):

There is a [similar answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/55960/44179) on how to install JDK 8

### Install the JRE

[Download](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) the 32-bit or 64-bit Linux "compressed binary file" - it has a ".tar.gz" file extension and uncompress it

```
tar -xvf jre-7-linux-i586.tar.gz
```

The JRE 7 package is extracted into ./jre1.7.0 directory. Now move the JRE 7 directory to `/usr/lib`:

```
sudo mv ./jre1.7.0* /usr/lib/jvm/jre1.7.0
```

Afterwards, run the following to get a list of currently installed Java alternatives.

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

You will get output as:

```
There are 2 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

Selection Path Priority Status
————————————————————
* 0 /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/bin/java 1061 auto mode
1 /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/bin/java 1061 manual mode
2 /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/jre/bin/java 63 manual mode

Press enter to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

Remember the last number and press enter to exit this utility i.e. in this example remember the number `2`.

If only one alternative is shown then remember the number `0`.

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /usr/lib/jvm/jre1.7.0/bin/java 3
```

This will add your new JRE 7 installation into the alternatives list i.e. use the remembered number + 1, that is, 3 in the example above. Now configure Java to use the Oracle Java JRE:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

You will see output similar one below - choose the number of jre1.7.0, that is, `3`:

```
There are 3 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

Selection Path Priority Status
————————————————————
* 0 /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/bin/java 1061 auto mode
1 /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/bin/java 1061 manual mode
2 /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/jre/bin/java 63 manual mode
3 /usr/lib/jvm/jre1.7.0/jre/bin/java 3 manual mode

Press enter to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: 3
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/jre1.7.0/jre/bin/java to provide /usr/bin/java (java) in manual mode.
```

N.B.: If there was no previous Java installation then the new JRE will be the default and you will not see the above.

Check the version of you new JRE 7 installation:

```
java -version
```

It should produce

```
java version “1.7.0”
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0-b147)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 21.0-b17, mixed mode)
```

### [Install the Firefox/Chrome plugin](https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/java)

In a terminal:

```
mkdir ~/.mozilla/plugins
```

Remove the IcedTea plugin, if it has been installed.

```
sudo apt-get remove icedtea6-plugin
```

Remove a former version of the Java plugin (may or may not be present):

```
rm ~/.mozilla/plugins/libnpjp2.so
```

Now you can install the plugin, by creating a symbolic link (you tell Firefox, where the plugin is located). For 32-bit Java use

```
ln -s /usr/lib/jvm/jre1.7.0/lib/i386/libnpjp2.so ~/.mozilla/plugins/
```

For 64-bit Java use

```
ln -s /usr/lib/jvm/jre1.7.0/lib/amd64/libnpjp2.so ~/.mozilla/plugins/
```

Confirm that the JRE has been successful by using the [official oracle website](http://java.com/en/download/installed.jsp).

Comment: After running `sudo update-alternatives --config java`, I get the following output:`There is only one alternative in link group java: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/bin/java
Nothing to configure.` What am I doing wrong?

Comment: great answer, thanks!  Wonder why Oracle can't spend the time to make packages for this....

Comment: @Shoan, in that case, go to step "if only one alternative is shown then remember the number 0"

Comment: Thank you for this answer, Oracles instructions are rubbish for a linux noob, this made things alot easier!

Comment: Thanks! Now I can finally use the Sun JVM! EDIT: crud, this breaks Minecraft on my 64-bit system. (Strange, considering that the specifically ask you to use Sun's JVM.) The launcher opens OK, but when I try to launch it, I get the Black Screen, even after deleting my `~/.minecraft/bin/` folder, and then updating. Running from the terminal, it gives me some gibberish about wrong ELF type, and that it's probably an architecture mismatch. (The official Java verifier on the Oracle site says everything's fine, though...)

Comment: Worth noting for those who have not got any previous version of Java installed, you do not need to preform the command `sudo update-alternatives --config java` (no need for either occurrence) It will not cause problems if you do though, it will simply give you a warning that there are no or only one alternative and nothing is to be configured

Comment: Do we have to do the same steps for an update?

Comment: While this method works - apt-get won't know that you have java installed.  So trying to install tools like ant, maven, etc will still want to install openjdk.  Instead something like http://www.webupd8.org/2012/01/install-oracle-java-jdk-7-in-ubuntu-via.html worked great for me!

Comment: What if `update-alternatives --config java` gives `update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for java`?

Comment: I really doubt that the latter instructions help for Chrome, ie does Chrome really read the settings for Firefox??

Comment: can you think of any need for firefox/chrome plugin for JRE on a production web server ? Also, It would be great if you could also add to this answer about how to update these installations later with security patches etc or newer versions(btw OP also asked for that already).

Comment: I think the package is called 'icedtea-6-plugin', ie with one more hyphen than in the answer. I am afraid to edit in such a popular/fantastic answer, but maybe someone dares too :)

Comment: Also, I believe a restart of Firefox is necessary, so maybe that should be added to the process.

Comment: I couldn't find `/.mozilla` instead I used `/usr/lib/firefox-addons/plugins` folder and it worked without restarting firefox. [Source](http://askubuntu.com/questions/383960/where-is-firefoxs-plugins-directory)

Comment: @Shoan I had the same error, however for Java to work in a browser was enough to skip the «alternatives» step, and make the symlink.

Answer (score 99):

Here is a tested and working solution for installing Oracle JDK 7 and all its files so "javac" and everything else works: [How To Install Oracle Java 7 (JDK) In Ubuntu](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/09/how-to-install-oracle-java-7-jdk-in.html)

Here are the commands (just for convenience):

1. Download the latest Oracle JDK 7 from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk-7u3-download-1501626.html).
2. Extract the downloaded Oracle Java JDK archive in your home folder - a new folder called "jdk1.7.0_03" (for Java JDK7 update 3) should be created. Rename it to "java-7-oracle" and move it to /usr/lib/jvm using the following commands:

> ```
> cd
> sudo mkdir -p /usr/lib/jvm/      #just in case
> sudo mv java-7-oracle/ /usr/lib/jvm/
> ```
>
> 3. Install Update Java package created by Bruce Ingalls (packages available for Ubuntu 11.10, 11.04, 10.10 and 10.04):
>
> ```
> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
> sudo apt-get update
> sudo apt-get install update-java
> ```
>
> 4. Now run the following command in a terminal to install Oracle Java JDK:
>
> ```
> sudo update-java
> ```
>
> [image: Select the Java Version that you want to install and set as the default]

After a few minutes, Oracle Java JDK should be successfully installed on your Ubuntu machine. You can check out the version by running these commands in a terminal:

> ```
> java -version
> javac -version
> ```

---

> **NOTICE!  This part below here of this answer no longer works due to Java changing how their binaries are released. It has been left as-is for historical reasons.**

Update Oracle has released Java 8 (stable). To install it, use the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

More information @ WebUpd8: [Install Oracle Java 8 In Ubuntu Via PPA Repository [JDK8]](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/09/install-oracle-java-8-in-ubuntu-via-ppa.html)

Comment: I think this script would work for Gnome (tools) but requires a lot of additional installs as for Kubuntu machine (eg. missing gksudo on Kubuntu).

Comment: good and relatively painless solution on Precise, just installed jdk1.7.0_03 on it

Comment: I just used this method to put jdk1.7.0_03 on Precise beta 2, as well.  It worked, although an error was reported (in Zenity, evidently); the error doesn't appear to have affected the result.

Comment: tried it on ubuntu 13.04 and it works. +1 
thanks

Comment: 1.7.0_40 works on xubuntu 13.04 too. fast and simple.

Comment: Add the information that, if we don't want to remove any existing jdk, then we should skip the first dialog which **delete existing jdk**

Answer (score 94):

> **NOTICE!  This solution no longer works due to Java changing how their binaries are released.  As a result, this answer is no longer valid.  It has been left as-is for historical reasons.**

From http://www.webupd8.org/2012/01/install-oracle-java-jdk-7-in-ubuntu-via.html :

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-jdk7-installer
```

- [Are PPAs safe to add to my system and what are some "red flags" to watch out for?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35629/are-ppas-safe-to-add-to-my-system-and-what-are-some-red-flags-to-watch-out)

Comment: I am wondering why most people are tempted to use the first answer, which is quite complex and requires a lot of manual work, like downloading the installer on your machine and moving it to the server. Your answer is simple and effective!!! TX

Comment: @SorinSbarnea Some people don't like to use third party repositories because they aren't always updated or online for that matter.

Comment: On Ubuntu server, I had to use "sudo apt-get install python-software-properties" to get the add-apt-repository command.

Comment: @SorinSbarnea because the repository is generally well out of date

Comment: @sorin some of us are working with multiple java versions, and the first answer kinda reminds us of verifying which version is currently active

Comment: I love manual works, because I want to know what are going on

Comment: Note that that Webupd8 PPA also contains a script which will set Oracle Java as default (useful if you have multiple JRE's / JDKs installed), install it with `sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-set-default`. Also note that this answer is a bit out of date,  you should probably be installing `oracle-java8-installer` these days.

Comment: This no longer works, the `webupd8team/java` PPA has been discontinued.

Answer (score 40):

This is how I installed it in Oneiric just now. It will be a rather lengthy answer, but it worked for me.

Download latest Java SDK 1.7.0 from Oracle. Then extract it to */usr/lib/jvm*:

```
cd /usr/lib/jvm/
sudo tar -xvzf ~/jdk-7-linux-x64.tar.gz
sudo mv jdk1.7.0 java-7-oracle
sudo ln -s java-7-oracle java-1.7.0-oracle
```

After that I created *.java-1.7.0-oracle.jinfo* file in /usr/lib/jvm with the following contents:

```
alias=java-7-oracle
priority=100
section=non-free

jre ControlPanel /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/ControlPanel
jre java /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/java
jre java_vm /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/java_vm
jre javaws /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/javaws
jre jcontrol /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/jcontrol
jre keytool /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/keytool
jre pack200 /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/pack200
jre policytool /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/policytool
jre rmid /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/rmid
jre rmiregistry /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/rmiregistry
jre unpack200 /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/unpack200
jre orbd /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/orbd
jre servertool /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/servertool
jre tnameserv /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/tnameserv
jre jexec /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/lib/jexec
jdk appletviewer /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/appletviewer
jdk apt /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/apt
jdk extcheck /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/extcheck
jdk idlj /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/idlj
jdk jar /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/jar
jdk jarsigner /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/jarsigner
jdk java-rmi.cgi /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/java-rmi.cgi
jdk javac /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/javac
jdk javadoc /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/javadoc
jdk javah /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/javah
jdk javap /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/javap
jdk jconsole /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/jconsole
jdk jdb /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/jdb
jdk jhat /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/jhat
jdk jinfo /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/jinfo
jdk jmap /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/jmap
jdk jps /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/jps
jdk jrunscript /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/jrunscript
jdk jsadebugd /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/jsadebugd
jdk jstack /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/jstack
jdk jstat /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/jstat
jdk jstatd /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/jstatd
jdk native2ascii /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/native2ascii
jdk rmic /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/rmic
jdk schemagen /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/schemagen
jdk serialver /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/serialver
jdk wsgen /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/wsgen
jdk wsimport /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/wsimport
jdk xjc /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/xjc
plugin xulrunner-1.9-javaplugin.so /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/libnpjp2.so
plugin mozilla-javaplugin.so /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/libnpjp2.so
```

Then you need to tell update-alternatives about all the new stuff:

```
$ sudo -sH
Password:
# update-alternatives --quiet --install /usr/lib/xulrunner-addons/plugins/libjavaplugin.so xulrunner-1.9-javaplugin.so /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/libnpjp2.so 100
# update-alternatives --quiet --install /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/libjavaplugin.so mozilla-javaplugin.so /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/libnpjp2.so 100
# update-alternatives --quiet --install /usr/bin/appletviewer appletviewer /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/appletviewer 100 --slave /usr/share/man/man1/appletviewer.1 appletviewer.1 /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/man/man1/appletviewer.1
# update-alternatives --quiet --install /usr/bin/apt apt /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/apt 100 --slave /usr/share/man/man1/apt.1 apt.1 /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/man/man1/apt.1
# update-alternatives --quiet --install /usr/bin/extcheck extcheck /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/extcheck 100 --slave /usr/share/man/man1/extcheck.1 extcheck.1 /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/man/man1/extcheck.1
# update-alternatives --quiet --install /usr/bin/idlj idlj /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/idlj 100 --slave /usr/share/man/man1/idlj.1 idlj.1 /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/man/man1/idlj.1
# update-alternatives --quiet --install /usr/bin/jar jar /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/jar 100 --slave /usr/share/man/man1/jar.1 jar.1 /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/man/man1/jar.1
# update-alternatives --quiet --install /usr/bin/jarsigner jarsigner /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/jarsigner 100 --slave /usr/share/man/man1/jarsigner.1 jarsigner.1 /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/man/man1/jarsigner.1
# update-alternatives --quiet --install /usr/bin/javac javac /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/javac 100 --slave /usr/share/man/man1/javac.1 javac.1 /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/man/man1/javac.1
# update-alternatives --quiet --install /usr/bin/javadoc javadoc /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/javadoc 100 --slave /usr/share/man/man1/javadoc.1 javadoc.1 /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/man/man1/javadoc.1
# update-alternatives --quiet --install /usr/bin/javah javah /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/javah 100 --slave /usr/share/man/man1/javah.1 javah.1 /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/man/man1/javah.1
# update-alternatives --quiet --install /usr/bin/javap javap /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/javap 100 --slave /usr/share/man/man1/javap.1 javap.1 /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/man/man1/javap.1
# update-alternatives --quiet --install /usr/bin/jconsole jconsole /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/jconsole 100 --slave /usr/share/man/man1/jconsole.1 jconsole.1 /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/man/man1/jconsole.1
# update-alternatives --quiet --install /usr/bin/jdb jdb /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/jdb 100 --slave /usr/share/man/man1/jdb.1 jdb.1 /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/man/man1/jdb.1
# update-alternatives --quiet --install /usr/bin/jhat jhat /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/jhat 100 --slave /usr/share/man/man1/jhat.1 jhat.1 /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/man/man1/jhat.1
# update-alternatives --quiet --install /usr/bin/jinfo jinfo /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/jinfo 100 --slave /usr/share/man/man1/jinfo.1 jinfo.1 /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/man/man1/jinfo.1
# update-alternatives --quiet --install /usr/bin/jmap jmap /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/jmap 100 --slave /usr/share/man/man1/jmap.1 jmap.1 /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/man/man1/jmap.1
# update-alternatives --quiet --install /usr/bin/jps jps /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/jps 100 --slave /usr/share/man/man1/jps.1 jps.1 /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/man/man1/jps.1
# update-alternatives --quiet --install /usr/bin/jrunscript jrunscript /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/jrunscript 100 --slave /usr/share/man/man1/jrunscript.1 jrunscript.1 /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/man/man1/jrunscript.1
# update-alternatives --quiet --install /usr/bin/jsadebugd jsadebugd /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/jsadebugd 100 --slave /usr/share/man/man1/jsadebugd.1 jsadebugd.1 /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/man/man1/jsadebugd.1
# update-alternatives --quiet --install /usr/bin/jstack jstack /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/jstack 100 --slave /usr/share/man/man1/jstack.1 jstack.1 /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/man/man1/jstack.1
# update-alternatives --quiet --install /usr/bin/jstat jstat /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/jstat 100 --slave /usr/share/man/man1/jstat.1 jstat.1 /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/man/man1/jstat.1
# update-alternatives --quiet --install /usr/bin/jstatd jstatd /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/jstatd 100 --slave /usr/share/man/man1/jstatd.1 jstatd.1 /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/man/man1/jstatd.1
# update-alternatives --quiet --install /usr/bin/native2ascii native2ascii /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/native2ascii 100 --slave /usr/share/man/man1/native2ascii.1 native2ascii.1 /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/man/man1/native2ascii.1
# update-alternatives --quiet --install /usr/bin/rmic rmic /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/rmic 100 --slave /usr/share/man/man1/rmic.1 rmic.1 /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/man/man1/rmic.1
# update-alternatives --quiet --install /usr/bin/schemagen schemagen /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/schemagen 100 --slave /usr/share/man/man1/schemagen.1 schemagen.1 /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/man/man1/schemagen.1
# update-alternatives --quiet --install /usr/bin/serialver serialver /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/serialver 100 --slave /usr/share/man/man1/serialver.1 serialver.1 /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/man/man1/serialver.1
# update-alternatives --quiet --install /usr/bin/wsgen wsgen /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/wsgen 100 --slave /usr/share/man/man1/wsgen.1 wsgen.1 /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/man/man1/wsgen.1
# update-alternatives --quiet --install /usr/bin/wsimport wsimport /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/wsimport 100 --slave /usr/share/man/man1/wsimport.1 wsimport.1 /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/man/man1/wsimport.1
# update-alternatives --quiet --install /usr/bin/xjc xjc /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/xjc 100 --slave /usr/share/man/man1/xjc.1 xjc.1 /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/man/man1/xjc.1
# update-alternatives --quiet --install /usr/bin/java-rmi.cgi java-rmi.cgi /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/java-rmi.cgi 100
# update-alternatives --quiet --install /usr/bin/ControlPanel ControlPanel /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/ControlPanel 100
# update-alternatives --quiet --install /usr/bin/java java /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/java 100
# update-alternatives --quiet --install /usr/bin/java_vm java_vm /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/java_vm 100
# update-alternatives --quiet --install /usr/bin/javaws javaws /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/javaws 100
# update-alternatives --quiet --install /usr/bin/jcontrol jcontrol /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/jcontrol 100
# update-alternatives --quiet --install /usr/bin/keytool keytool /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/keytool 100
# update-alternatives --quiet --install /usr/bin/pack200 pack200 /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/pack200 100
# update-alternatives --quiet --install /usr/bin/policytool policytool /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/policytool 100
# update-alternatives --quiet --install /usr/bin/rmid rmid /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/rmid 100
# update-alternatives --quiet --install /usr/bin/rmiregistry rmiregistry /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/rmiregistry 100
# update-alternatives --quiet --install /usr/bin/unpack200 unpack200 /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/unpack200 100
# update-alternatives --quiet --install /usr/bin/orbd orbd /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/orbd 100
# update-alternatives --quiet --install /usr/bin/servertool servertool /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/servertool 100
# update-alternatives --quiet --install /usr/bin/tnameserv tnameserv /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/tnameserv 100
# update-alternatives --quiet --install /usr/bin/jexec jexec /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/lib/jexec 100
```

Now you can use update-alternatives to select newly installed Java SDK.

```
# update-alternatives --config java              # Select java-1.7.0-oracle
# update-java-alternatives --set java-1.7.0-oracle
# exit
$
```

This worked for me, if there is a more elegant way (without using third-party PPAs) I'd be glad to hear about it. I still need to test Firefox if I can run Java in it.

Comment: Works great, except the final command issues an error (though everything else works, even in Firefox/Chrome). This seems to be from the default OpenJDK6 install with Oneiric."update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for -javaplugin.so."
In the hidden .java.1.6.0.jinfo file there seems to be an alternative pointing to -javaplugin.so. Are we supposed to make a 3rd alternative point to libnpjp2.so with it perhaps?

Comment: I decided to put the steps mentioned by [BigWhale](http://askubuntu.com/users/23704/bigwhale) above in a simple shell script. The only manual step is to download the 64bit tar.gz from Oracle's site. [Have a look at the instructions here.](https://github.com/jvassev/install-jdk/)

Comment: This is the only solution that shows how to add the man pages!

Comment: @DavidG Alien Andrei's solution also works flawlessly

Comment: Also this solution is for 64bit Ubuntu. for 32bit, we should have `i386` instead of `amd64`

Answer (score 25):

> **Note:** WebUpd8 team's PPA has been discontinued with effective from April 16, 2019. Thus this PPA doesn't have any Java files. More information can be found on [PPA's page on Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/java). Hence this method no longer works and exists here only for historical reasons.

**An updated answer:**

I suggest using one of the installers from the **webupd8team ppa** in this way:

1. Enter these 2 commands in the Terminal to add this PPA and update your packages list:

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
   sudo apt-get update
   ```
2. Enter one (or more) of these commands to install the proprietary Java(s) you require:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install oracle-java6-installer
   sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
   sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
   sudo apt-get install oracle-java9-installer
   ```
3. When the respective Java installer script is loaded and then it downloads and installs the proprietary Java packages, you can also enter the following command to check the result of the installation:

   ```
   java -version
   ```

You should then get a terminal output (for java8 stable version) like this:

```
java version "1.8.0_72"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_72-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.72-b15, mixed mode)
```

Further info: http://www.webupd8.org/2012/09/install-oracle-java-8-in-ubuntu-via-ppa.html

*NB: These packages provide Oracle Java JDK, which includes Java JDK, JRE and the Java browser plugin. And the webupd8team/java PPA contains only these installers, which simply connect to Oracle Java download site and install the latest JDK.*

Comment: Thanks for answer. Only this way made my Chrome JRE worked!

Comment: does it install just the jre or entire jdk, if entire jdk, then what's way to restrict installation only to jre ?

Comment: does this type of installation provide me with automatic updates as they are released & wont adding this ppa add other kinds of softwares unknowingly to my server?

Comment: This installs the **JDK**: "This package provides Oracle Java JDK 7 (which includes Java JDK, JRE and the Java browser plugin). _However, you can't only install Oracle JRE_ - the PPA only provides the full Oracle JDK7 package." [ref](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/01/install-oracle-java-jdk-7-in-ubuntu-via.html)

Answer (score 16):

> **Note:** WebUpd8 team's PPA has been discontinued with effective from April 16, 2019. Thus this PPA doesn't have any Java files. More information can be found on [PPA's page on Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/java). Hence this method no longer works and exists because of historical reasons.

I appreciate all the previous answers. I want to add this answer to simplify things which is done by [www.webupd8.org](http://www.webupd8.org) to make installation in **2-5 minutes**.

This installation includes:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
```

That's all!!
Now to check the Java version

```
java -version
```

The output will be like

```
java version "1.7.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_25-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode
```

There may come a new version, and then you can simply update it with this command:

```
sudo update-java-alternatives -s java-7-oracle
```

**Setting up environment variables**

```
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-set-default
```

For more, check out [Install Oracle Java 7 in Ubuntu via PPA Repository](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/01/install-oracle-java-jdk-7-in-ubuntu-via.html).

Comment: 2-5 minute? it took 77 minutes

Comment: Nice solution. This should be upvoted higher up. The installation time may take longer than 5 minutes depending on your internet speed (the download is ~70MB). As for setting the default Java machine, I prefer: `sudo update-alternatives --config java`.

Answer (score 15):

This solution will give you clean built packages just as they used to ship with Ubuntu before Oracle came around.

### The answer

First the answer, then the explanation. Open a terminal and copy and paste the following, line by line.

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ladios/oab-java6/master/oab-java.sh -O oab-java.sh
chmod +x oab-java.sh
sudo ./oab-java.sh
```

This will build the official sun-java6-* packages and make them available in the software-center. If you also want oracle-java7-* packages, run the script like this:

```
sudo ./oab-java.sh -7
```

Now you can install the packages with your preferred package manager.

### The explanation

When Oracle changed the distribution license for Java, Linux distributions weren't allowed to update the official packages anymore. Github user rraptorr took the Debian script that was used to build the packages until then, and modified it to work with the updated downloads from Oracle. He now provides packging scripts for [SUN Java6](https://github.com/rraptorr/sun-java6) and [Oracle Java7](https://github.com/rraptorr/oracle-java7).

The [oab.java.sh](https://github.com/ladios/oab-java6) script is just a wrapper that automatically downloads the current version, creates the packages and adds them to a local repository.

### Further notes

Packages created and installed using this method, will not receive updates automatically - only when you rerun the script. You can circumvent this by creating a cronjob that runs this script on a regular basis. The savest way to do this is using anacron by putting the script in */etc/cron.daily*.

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ladios/oab-java6/master/oab-java.sh -O /root/oab-java.sh
chmod +x /root/oab-java.sh
ln -s /root/oab-java.sh /etc/cron.daily/oab-java
```

Now your official Java packages will always be up-to-date.

Comment: I've had so many issues with this script -_-

Comment: @qodeninja, like what? I've never had an issue with this script. Executing the 3 line above will definately work on every Ubuntu machine, if it is not broken.

Comment: I have a new linode instance of ubuntu 10.04 and I was trying to install jre 7 with this script. The script would hang for far too long because of missing dependencies. Then I had to stop the script and install the dependencies myself with apt-get. Even after I had everything installed the script still failed.

Comment: The script really doesn't do anything special. Sounds like something is wrong with your box. I have been (and am) using this from 8.04 to 12.04 and never had problems. I just tried this on my 10.04 server which is pretty much vanilla, and it works as well. As it should, because this script doesn't do more than use the old debian build-scripts that packagers used to provide sun-java* for debian (and ubuntu).

Comment: On Lubuntu 15.04 It starts fine, but after a while I get `debian/rules:67: recipe for target 'get-orig-source' failed
make: *** [get-orig-source] Error 22
make: Leaving directory '/var/local/oab/src'
11678's retcode: 2
failed
`

Comment: Is this still needed? What is the benefint against installing java over the PPA from  ppa:webupd8team/java? (first answer here)

Answer (score 10):

This worked for my development needs of being able to run/compile 1.6 or 1.7.  Previously I was just running 1.6 from a Ubuntu apt package.

1. Download [1.7 gzip](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html).
2. Extract to folder
3. Update JAVA_HOME and PATH in bash file

   ```
   JAVA_HOME=/opt/java/jdk1.7.0_25
   export JAVA_HOME

   PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
   export PATH
   ```

Answer (score 9):

On AMD64 you need modify a little the command to create the symbolic link:

```
ln -s /usr/lib/jvm/jre1.7.0/lib/amd64/libnpjp2.so ~/.mozilla/plugins/
```

only change the `i386` to `amd64`.

Comment: Good shout! Wasn't working on my 12.04 64-bit until I read your answer. Thanks!

Comment: -1. This answer is completely out of context..

Comment: It's not the answer of the question. Instead, it should be a comment

Answer (score 7):

Get the JDK from Oracle/Sun; download the Java JDK at:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/overview/index.html

Please download or move the downloaded file to your home directory, `~`, for ease.

Note:

- Don't worry about what JDK to download for JEE.
- Please skip copying the Prompt " user@host:~$ ".
- Hit enter after each command.

Run in a terminal..

```
user@host:~$ sudo mkdir -p /usr/lib/jvm/
user@host:~$ sudo mv jdk-7u4-linux-i586.tar.gz /usr/lib/jvm/
user@host:~$ cd /usr/lib/jvm/
user@host:~$ sudo tar zxvf jdk-7u4-linux-i586.tar.gz
```

Now enable Java (by running individually):

```
user@host:~$ sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_04/bin/java" 1
user@host:~$ sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javac" "javac" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_04/bin/javac" 1
user@host:~$ sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javaws" "javaws" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_04/bin/javaws" 1
```

Close all browsers.

Create a Mozilla plugins folder in your home directory:

```
user@host:~$ mkdir ~/.mozilla/plugins/
```

Create a symbolic link to your Mozilla plugins folder. For 64-bit systems, replace ‘i386’ with ‘amd64’:

```
user@host:~$ ln -s /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0/jre/lib/i386/libnpjp2.so ~/.mozilla/plugins/
```

Testing:

```
user@host:~$ java -version
```

Output:

```
java version "1.7.0_04"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_04-b20)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 23.0-b21, mixed mode)
```

Testing:

```
user@host:~$ javac -version
```

Output:

```
javac 1.7.0_04
```

Verify JRE at http://java.com/en/download/installed.jsp.

Answer (score 7):

To make it available for all users :

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/jvm/jre1.7.0/lib/i386/libnpjp2.so /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/
```

for x86_64 :

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/jvm/jre1.7.0/lib/amd64/libnpjp2.so /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/
```

Comment: Many thanks! This is what was missing for my java to work on firefox.

Answer (score 5):

I propose one way to make easier the installation of Oracle's Java 7.

Since Ubuntu does not provides the Oracle's Java 7 packages, I'm providing a collection of Ubuntu packages on my own package repository.

The packages are fully integrated in the Ubuntu way to support Java. You will be able to select the Oracle's Java 7 alternative with the standard tools: update-alternative or update-java-alternative.

The main page of my contribution is: http://www.arakhne.org/jdk/index.html

To obtain the packages, you only need to add my package repository into your system configuration. The process is explained in http://www.arakhne.org/ubuntu.html

Stéphane.

Comment: ... just friendly advice - check oracle's redistribution license ... you dont want oracle's lawyers chasing you!

Comment: Please do not post duplicate answers on different questions. It just creates more work for the moderators. If the questions are so similar that the same answer works on each, then the later of the two is likely a duplicate and should be flagged as such.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way is just downloading java 7 with Netbeans here - http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk-7-netbeans-download-432126.html

Answer (score 4):

> **Note:** WebUpd8 team's PPA has been discontinued with effective from April 16, 2019. Thus this PPA doesn't have any Java files. More information can be found on [PPA's page on Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/java). Hence this method no longer works and exists because of historical reasons.

For those who live in Syria, Cuba, Libya, Korea or any country where Oracle is banning its services, this is a working way to install Oracle JDK 8.

1. Using a PROXY, go to [this link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) and accept the terms then download the tar.gz suitable to your system (32 or 64 bit).
2. Move that tarball to the Downloads directory in your home folder.
3. run [this script](https://gist.github.com/TamerShlash/f9519fd570a9b0d76165) as sudo:

```
if [[ $UID != 0 ]]; then
  echo "This script neeeds to be run with sudo, like this:"
  echo -e "\n  sudo $0 $*\n"
  exit 1
fi
apt-get install python-software-properties
add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
apt-get update
apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
if [ ! -f $HOME/Downloads/jdk-8u5-linux-*.tar.gz ]; then
  echo "The JDK tar.gz file was not found in $HOME/Downloads. please download it, put it in $HOME/Downloads and run again."
  exit 1
fi
cp ~/Downloads/jdk-8u5-linux-*.tar.gz /var/cache/oracle-jdk8-installer/
apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
apt-get install oracle-java8-set-default
java -version
```

Answer (score 3):

For me it's a little bit different. For Ubuntu 12.04 LTS Precise (Desktop):

1. Download `jre-*.tar.gz`
2. `tar -zxvf jre-*.tar.gz`
3. `mkdir /usr/lib/jvm/`
4. `mv jre* /usr/lib/jvm/`
5. `ln -s /usr/lib/jvm/jre*/bin/java /usr/bin/`

That's all.

To make sure it's correct:

```
java -version
```

If you want to add plug in for Firefox or Chrome:

1. `mkdir ~/.mozilla/plugins`
2. `ln -s /usr/lib/jvm/jre*/lib/i386/libnpjp2.so ~/.mozilla/plugins/`

Special Note:  If you have a fresh 64 bit install, you may experience the following error when running `java -version`

```
-bash: ./java: No such file or directory
```

This is caused by a dependency on the `libc6-i386` package which is not included by default in 64 bit Ubuntu Desktop 12.04 LTS.  To install this package, run: 
`sudo apt-get install libc6-i386`

Comment: The instructions you provide to add a plugin for Firefox or Chrome do not affect Chrome at all. Chrome does not use the contents of the `.mozilla` folder.

Answer (score 3):

I think that the best method has been already posted but I had some problem with this : namely I remove java 'manually' from `update-alternatives` and then I have tried to do this

`update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java/" "java" "/usr/lib/jvm/jre1.7.0_05/bin/java" 1`

but I kept on getting this error

> update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/jre1.7.0_05/bin/java to
>   provide /usr/bin/java/ (java) in auto mode. update-alternatives:
>   error: unable to make /usr/bin/java/.dpkg-tmp a symlink to
>   /etc/alternatives/java: No such file or directory

But fortunately I have encountered a great tutorial on this site : http://www.webupd8.org/2012/01/install-oracle-java-jdk-7-in-ubuntu-via.html and it worked just fine :)

Comment: `/usr/bin/java` is not a folder, that's why the error

Answer (score 3):

For installing the 32-bit variant of Java on 64-bit Ubuntu:

Open up a **terminal** window ( <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> is the quickest method if you're not aware) and type in the following to install:

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://download.tuxfamily.org/arakhne/ubuntu precise-arakhne universe"

wget http://download.tuxfamily.org//arakhne/public.key -O - | sudo apt-key add -
apt-get install ia32-oracle-java7-jre
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a bash script that could help in setting up the java alternatives:

```
#!/bin/bash

BIN_HOME="/usr/bin"
JVM_BIN_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_21/bin"

UPDATE_CMD="update-alternatives"
UPDATE_OPT="--install"
UPDATE_DEFAULT_PRIORITY=10

echo "Installing alternatives for Oracle JDK."
#echo "JAVA_BIN_HOME=$JAVA_BIN_HOME"
#echo "BIN_HOM=$BIN_HOME"
echo "All cmds in \"$JVM_BIN_HOME\" will be installed in \"$BIN_HOME\" with \"$UPDATE_CMD\""
echo

# 
# Calls update-alternatives.
# Param 1 is the java cmd name and optionally param 2 is the priority
# See 'man update-alternatives' for more information.
# 
function update_alt() {
    if [ -z "$2" -o "${2}xxx" = "xxx" ]; then
    echo "using default priority: $UPDATE_DEFAULT_PRIORITY"
    PRIORITY=$UPDATE_DEFAULT_PRIORITY
    else
    PRIORITY=$2
    fi

    EXEC="$UPDATE_CMD $UPDATE_OPT $BIN_HOME/$1 $1 $JVM_BIN_HOME/$1 $PRIORITY"
    echo $EXEC
    $EXEC
    return 0
}

for bin in $JVM_BIN_HOME/*
do
    if [ -x $bin ]; then
    cmd=$(basename $bin)

    if [ -x $BIN_HOME/$cmd ]; then
        echo "notice: alternative already installed, \"$cmd\""
        continue # Skip installation of alternative.
    fi

    echo "install alternative: $cmd"
    update_alt $cmd
    if [ ! -x $BIN_HOME/$cmd ]; then
        echo "error: failed to install alternative, \"$cmd\""
        exit 1
    fi
    fi
done

exit 0
```

Answer (score 3):

**Straightforward Solution**

Rather than downloading the `.tar.gz` package I recommend you download the `.rpm` package. Then run:

```
sudo apt-get install alien dpkg-dev debhelper build-essential
sudo alien --scripts jdk-7u-linux-.rpm
```

where I believe the current `<build>` is 21 and the  `<version>` depends on your system architecture.

The first will install alien, a application for converting `.rpm` to `.deb`. The second command then runs alien on jdk package. This should run for a minute or two and produce a file labelled:

`jdk-7u<build>-linux-<version>.deb`

This package may then be installed by running:

```
sudo dpkg -i jdk-7u<build>-linux-<version>.deb
```

This is how I successfully installed it on my machine.

Comment: Would this update the alternatives? probably only copy the files.

Answer (score 2):

The best method that I can deliver if you want to install **Java 6** under [Ubuntu 12.04 LTS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ubuntu_releases#Ubuntu_12.04_LTS_.28Precise_Pangolin.29) (Precise Pangolin) is:

```
sudo apt-get purge sun-java
```

You need to do that if you want the Mozilla plugin to work without conflict with Java 7 for instance.

```
mkdir ~/src

cd ~/src
git clone https://github.com/flexiondotorg/oab-java6.git
cd ~/src/oab-java6
sudo ./oab-java.sh
```

Then when it's finished, install Java:

```
sudo apt-get install sun-java6-plugin sun-java6-jre sun-java6-bin sun-java6-jdk
```

You can follow the installation process with:

```
tail -f ~/src/oab-java6/oab-java.sh.log
```

**Explanation**: the same as in an answer to [How can I install Sun/Oracle's proprietary Java JDK 6/7/8 or JRE?](https://askubuntu.com/a/173951/159179).

**Ref**: [Installing Java6 JDK on Ubuntu 12.04](http://www.gaggl.com/2012/04/installing-java6-jdk-on-ubuntu-12-04/)

Answer (score 2):

To me the Debian way (sic) would be to create your own package.

You install `java-package`

```
sudo apt-get install java-package
```

You download the Oracle tar.gz archive.

You create your deb package

```
fakeroot make-jpkg jdk-7u79-linux-x64.tar.gz
```

An you install it

```
sudo dpkg -i oracle-java7-jdk_7u79_amd64.deb
```

Answer (score 2):

Download your desired `.tar.gz` version of JDK for your Ubuntu system from `http://oracle.com`, for example `jdk-8u102-linux-x64.tar.gz`.

Extract it to anywhere you want in `/home` directory, for example `/home/dante/Programs/Java`. Now we have a folder with the name like `jdk1.8.0_102` inside `/home/dante/Programs/Java`.

Add these two lines to your `/home/dante/.profile` file

```
export JAVA_HOME=/home/dante/Programs/Java/jdk1.8.0_102
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Restart your system and after reboot you should see your Java version by running `java -version` in terminal.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why people have given so much big answers but adding jdk/bin to PATH works just fine:-

- Download JDK from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html
- Exctract any whereve you want . I like `/opt`

  ex:- `tar -xvf jdk-9.0.1_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz -C /opt`

Add your `jdk/bin` to PATH as told [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58814/how-do-i-add-environment-variables) in my case this is how my `/etc/environment` looks:-

```
   $ cat /etc/environment     
   PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/opt/jdk-9.0.1/bin"    
   JAVA_HOME="/opt/jdk-9.0.1/"
```

Answer (score 1):

To install Sun Java 6 on Precise through Trusty, you can use the [Preserved Removed Primary/Partner Archive packages](https://launchpad.net/~maxb/+archive/preserved) PPA.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:maxb/preserved
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jre
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

And then select the desired Java version. You can check what you're now running by:

```
geek@liv-inspiron:/tmp$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_26"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_26-b03)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.1-b02, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 1):

## Installing Oracle Java (JDK/JRE):

You can automate the task of installing/uninstalling Oracle Java (JDK/JRE) from a downloaded (tar.gz) source with this script: [oraji](https://github.com/neurobin/oraji).

Steps:

1. [Download](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) the tar.gz source of your desired jdk/jre version.
2. run `sudo oraji /path/to/the/jdk_or_jre/archive`

## Uninstall:

run `sudo oraji -u` and confirm the jdk/jre version to be uninstalled.

Answer (score 1):

You can download the latest [Oracle JDK 8](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-jdk8-downloads.html), then you open a terminal with '**Ctrl + Alt + t**' and enter the following commands:

```
cd /usr/lib/jvm
```

*If the /usr/lib/jvm folder does not exist, enter this command will create the directory 
`sudo mkdir /usr/lib/jvm`*

Then extract the **jdk-{version}.tar.gz** file in that directory using this command.

```
sudo tar -xvzf ~/Downloads/jdk-{version}.tar.gz
```

The the following command to open the environment variables file.

```
sudo vim /etc/environment
```

In the opened file, add the following bin folders to the existing PATH variable.

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-{version}/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-{version}/db/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-{version}/jre/bin"
J2SDKDIR="/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-{version}"
J2REDIR="/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-{version}/jre"
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-{version}"
DERBY_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-{version}/db"
```

Save the changes and close the vim.

Then enter the following commands to inform the system about the Java's location.

```
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-{version}/bin/java" 0
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javac" "javac" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-{version}/bin/javac" 0
sudo update-alternatives --set java /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-{version}/bin/java
sudo update-alternatives --set javac /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-{version}/bin/javac
```

To verify the setup enter the following commands and make sure that they print the location of java and javac as you have provided in the previous step.

```
update-alternatives --list java
update-alternatives --list javac
```

Now restart the terminal again and enter following commands.

```
java -version
javac -version
```

If you get the installed Java version as the output, you have successfully installed the Oracle JDK in your system.

Answer (score 0):

OS: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

I am surprised no one has mentioned `conda` . Link:
https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html

I installed java in one of my conda environments and used the `java` command without problems.